# Deleting Rows in a Database Table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

What's the easiest way to delete rows in a database table using Entity Framework 6?

I just pulled down EF6 via NuGet and have been able to successfully query rows from the DB.  However, I do not seem to have access to the `context.<entity>.Delete()` or `context.<entity>.DeleteObject()` methods, which are most often shown as examples online.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working.

```
var query = <linq query>;

context.<entity>.RemoveRange(query);
context.SaveChanges();
```